# Чтение одной таблицы базы данных большим кол-вом инстансов

Tags: база-данных, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть таблица, которая очень быстро заполняется данными. Я должен их быстро читать и анализировать. (максимум 10 секунд)
Для этого я запускаю 5-10 инстансов своего приложения.

Я не могу найти правильный подход. Как правильно читать одну таблицу несколькими инстансами приложения так чтобы каждый не дублировал данные.

Я вижу это так, каждый инстанс после прочтения ставит флаг (прочитано). Но остальные инстансы будут ждать (если делать с пассивной блокировкой)

Comment: Сделай одно приложение-читатель, которое обслуживает 10 приложений анализаторов.

Comment: Что-то такое: [издатель-подписчик (шаблон проектирования)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).